# How to make ctrlp to include extra directories beside cwd

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, ctrlp

ctrlp in vim takes the current working directory and it's containing folder for searching files.

Is it possible to tell ctrlp to include some other directories also beside current working directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:help CtrlP
```

You can set the starting directory yourself using `:CtrlP /path/to/dir`; however, AFAIK, you can't search several directories at the same time.